# Downloading files with curl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl

I tried downloading the csv files from [this](https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/index.php/s/2DhnLGDdEECo4ys?path=%2FUNSW-NB15%20-%20CSV%20Files) repository from the command line of ubuntu 20.
What i have tried so far:

```
curl --output /home/../test2.csv https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/s/2DhnLGDdEECo4ys/download?path=%2FUNSW-NB15%20-%20CSV%20Files&files=UNSW-NB15_1.csv
```

However this creates a csv with unknown characters as input that can't be opened by excel ( if i download it from the browser everything is ok).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your url `https://example.net/xxx/download?path=yyy&files=zzz.csv` contains a `&`, so your shell will cut the url on that character and try to download only `https://example.net/xxx/download?path=yyy` and launch `curl` in background.

To fix the problem, just use quotes `"`:

```
curl --output test.csv "https://example.net/xxx/download?path=yyy&files=zzz.csv"
```

Comment: You may also need `--insecure` before `--output`, if the download takes place in a corporate environment (without access to the CA and/or with traffic decryption / filtering).